# the python x=x+x is 120 times slower than y=x+x?! why?

Tags: python, performance

I recently used the timeit module to do a very simple performance test of the python. The result really stunned me: the time consumed by `x=x+x` is about **125 times** of `x+x` or `y=x+x,` why?! I really hope someone will give me some clue about this, maybe I used the timeit wrong? Thanks!

Please notice that `y=x+x;x=y` is as slow as `x=x+x`… but the `x=x+47` is as fast as `x+x`

> testBasicOps()
>
> testcase="pass", time lapse:0.001487secs
>
> testcase="x=47", time lapse:0.002424secs
>
> testcase="x=94", time lapse:0.002423secs
>
> testcase="x=47*2", time lapse:0.002423secs
>
> **testcase="x+x", time lapse:0.003922secs**
>
> testcase="x*2", time lapse:0.005307secs
>
> **testcase="x=x+x", time lapse:0.497974secs**
>
> testcase="x=x*2", time lapse:0.727506secs
>
> **testcase="x=x+47", time lapse:0.005770secs**
>
> testcase="x=47+x", time lapse:0.004442secs
>
> **testcase="x+=x", time lapse:0.498920secs**
>
> **testcase="y=x+x", time lapse:0.004102secs**
>
> testcase="y=x*2", time lapse:0.006327secs
>
> **testcase="y=x+x**
>
> **x=y", time lapse:0.499644secs**
>
> testcase="x+x
>
> y=x", time lapse:0.004948secs
>
> testcase="x+x
>
> x=y", time lapse:0.005126secs
>
> testcase="y=10
>
> x=y", time lapse:0.003351secs
>
> testcase="pass", time lapse:0.001487secs

The code I used:

```
import timeit
import numpy as npy
def testBasicOps():
    timeitSetup="""
x=47
y=0
"""
    testCases=['pass','x=47',\
               'x=94','x=47*2'\
               ,'x+x','x*2'\
               ,'x=x+x','x=x*2'\
               ,'x=x+47','x=47+x'\
               ,'x+=x','y=x+x'\
               ,'y=x*2','y=x+x\nx=y'\
               ,'x+x\ny=x','x+x\nx=y'\
               ,'y=10\nx=y']
    minT=[]
    tests=[]
    for i in testCases:
        tests.append(timeit.Timer(i,setup=timeitSetup))
        minT.append(npy.mean(tests[-1].repeat(10,int(1e5))))
        print 'testcase=\"%s\", time lapse:%fsecs'%(i,minT[-1])

def main():
    print "#"*10
    print "testBasicOps()"
    testBasicOps()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What version of python are you using? I have a feeling that this is caused by what casevh notes coupled with a version issue. I'm guessing you're on 2.6 or lower.

Comment: I would also mention that the code is very "Java-ish" and counter Python intuitive... you don't need the line continuations... just trail with a ',' to separate the list elements and go from there... eg. in `'pass','x=47',\` the '\' is unnecessary.

Comment: "@inspectorG4dget:What version of python are you using?"
sys.version= 2.7.2+ (default, Oct  4 2011, 20:06:09) 
[GCC 4.6.1]
Thanks everyone, especially @casevh! I fixed the problem by add "x=47;" in each test. It is definitely a usage problem of timeit module as I expected :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you compute `x=x+x` many thousands of times, `x` becomes a very large. You're measuring the length of time it takes to add two very large numbers.

Comment: Thanks! I see the problem now!

Comment: This seems to be it. set x to 0 instead of 47 initially and they take the same time.

Comment: yeah, if you add a line with `x=x+x;x=1` on it, everything goes away altogether

Comment: I also think that this might be a python <=2.6 problem. I get UnboundLocalError on python 2.7 because `x=47` doesn't "leak" into the next statement to be timed